# SQL to pick up and calculate SUM

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

I have 2 tables:

- Table 1 has 2 columns: Username and Join date
- Table 2 has 4 columns: Order No., Username, Sales date, Sales revenue

**How to calculate the total sales revenue of each Username within 30 days from Join date?** Thank you very much in advance!!!

Comment: welcome vuanhtu2811, could you please provide an example of both tables

Comment: Can you show us what you have so far?

Comment: Already upload image of 2 tables

Answer (score 1):

You can use `join` and aggregation:

```
select u.username, sum(revenue)
from users u left join
     orders o
     on o.username = u.username and
        o.salesdate < u.joindate + interval 30 day
group by u.username
```

Comment: What do "u" and "o" mean?

Comment: @vuanhtu2811 . . . They are table aliases, used to identify the tables in the query.